# Negative indexing with charindex() and substring function

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a column that holds the data in the following format:

```
Field Name
123_456_ABC_DEF
12_34_456_XYZ_PQR
LMN_OPQ_123_456
```

In each case I require, the last two block of data i.e.

```
ABC_DEF
XYZ_PQR
123_456
```

Is there a way to use `charindex()` in manner where it counts `'_'` from the right side of the string?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2017 or better and your values don't contain characters problematic to JSON, [this example might help](https://dbfiddle.uk/41Qw4lbX).

Comment: I hope that part of your project is to fix the design here. You seem to be violating 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. Those should separate columns instead of delimited by underscores.

Comment: Or if you are in SQL Server Azure, or SQL Server 2022 and your value does contain characters problematic to JSON then [this example may help](https://dbfiddle.uk/DRk7kPTg) (fiddle shamelessly copied from Aaron). I must confess though, as I don't have either of these versions myself, I have no idea how `STRING_SPLIT` with an ordinal stacks up against `OPEN_JSON` in terms of performance. Strongly agree with Sean though, if the smaller components have meaning of their own, then they should probably be stored separately

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an unreadable & slightly mad way of doing it :-)

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (tokens VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('123_456_ABC_DEF'),
('12_34_456_XYZ_PQR'),
('LMN_OPQ_123_456');

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(tokens),CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(tokens),CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(tokens))+1)-1))
FROM @tbl
```

Basically reversing the text, searching forwards & reversing it back at the end....(SQL Server T-SQL)

Comment: Slightly DRY-er version (avoids repeating `REVERSE(tokens)` three times) https://dbfiddle.uk/R4z-YejY - also seems you don't really need the final `REVERSE`. Once you know the string position you can subtract it from `LEN` and use substring

Comment: (example of 2nd approach https://dbfiddle.uk/UuyU6D9G)

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It is based on *tokenization* via XML and XQuery.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing input as XML.
- The XPath predicate `[position() ge (last()-1)]` gives us last two
  tokens.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (tokens VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('123_456_ABC_DEF'),
('12_34_456_XYZ_PQR'),
('LMN_OPQ_123_456');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '_';

SELECT t.*
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() ge (last()-1)])').value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)')
        , SPACE(1), @separator) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| tokens | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 123_456_ABC_DEF | ABC_DEF |
| 12_34_456_XYZ_PQR | XYZ_PQR |
| LMN_OPQ_123_456 | 123_456 |

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using JSON and a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Select NewValue = reverse(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')+'_'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'))
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape(reverse([Field Name]),'json'),'_','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
NewValue
ABC_DEF
XYZ_PQR
123_456
```